# Redirecting to Full Domain

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, redirect

I currently have a ASP .Net web application. I have some cross domain referencing in my application, so when users visit my page, I need to ensure they enter the full domain name.

So for example I need to redirect from

```
http://someserver/someapplication.page.aspx
```

to

```
http://someserver.domain.com/someapplication.page.aspx
```

I have the REGEx set up to catch the URL if it does not have the domain.com, also to hold anything after the 'someserver/', lets call this 'RegExMatch'. I just need to know what to call within to get the Full domain -

```
Response.Redirect({0}+RegexMatch);
```

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Use the properties in `Request.Url`.

Comment: I should add, I already looked ResolveURL/ResolveClientURL/System.Web.VirtualPathUtility.ToAboslute - all of these only go to someserver/ not fully qualified domain.

Comment: Is "someserver" the network name of the server? How are the users able to hit your server with just "http://someserver/"?

Comment: @SLaks the Request.Url also only give someserver/.

Comment: @Tombala - Yes it is registered with DNS on the network.

Comment: Apparently the settings can be changed at the IIS level. http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/seo-rule-templates. Will add as answer when SO allows me to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to do this in the IIS settings of the Application.

For anyone that is interested, here are the details. It is called Url Rewrite.
http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/seo-rule-templates.