# Redirect url to fully qualified name asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, url, redirect

I have website in my company that can be reached by typing, for example: `foo` in the location bar. And the site opens up with `foo/directoryOfWebsite/Welcome.aspx`.

I'd like to set it up instead to load `foo.companyServername.com/directoryOfWebsite/Welcome.aspx`. What settings should I make in which config file to expand the short name to the fully qualified domain name?

I would like to do this to avoid cross domain errors when trying to use ui tools created by other teams in the same firm.

I am new to C# and ASP .net. So I would request you to please explain in simple terms so that I can follow. I know that this is possible by configuring IIS in combination with URL-rewrite. But I am looking for something that can be done without all that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17055353/2179864

Comment: you have to do setting in IIS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for a way to redirect to another URL without having to configure anything on IIS side as such things are controlled by another team that takes care of windows infrastructure and stuff and might take longer to get done.

The quick way of doing this is to modify the `Website.Master.cs` file's `Page_Load` method.
Pasting a snippet below:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string domain = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
        var filePath = Request.Url.PathAndQuery;
        const string altDomainSuffix = "company.com";
        bool redirect = false;
        if (domain.ToLower().Contains("localhost"))
        {
            domain = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName().ToLower() + ".pc." + altDomainSuffix;
            redirect = true;
        }
        if (!domain.ToLower().Contains(altDomainSuffix))
        {
            domain = Request.Url.Host + ".prod." + altDomainSuffix;
            redirect = true;
        }
        if (redirect)
        {
            var altUrl = new UriBuilder(Request.Url.Scheme, domain + filePath);
            Response.Redirect(altUrl.ToString());
        }
    ...
    //other code goes here
    ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, you need to build foo domain on your web server and setup IIS accordingly.

Comment: This should be a comment under the original post, not an answer.