# IIS redirect to full domain name

Tags: iis, iis-7

I need to redirect from

`http://someserver/someapplication.page.aspx`
to
`http://someserver.domain.com/someapplication.page.aspx`

Both the requests lead to the same server.

`someserver/` works through our company's internal DNS

This is the same question as [Redirecting to Full Domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17046082/redirecting-to-full-domain)

but I want an IIS solution for this, not code. My guess is it will have something to do with adding a httpRedirect add element in Configuration Editor using wildcards.

Comment: looks like duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18006963/iis-url-rewrite-for-redirect-to-fqdn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use URL Rewrite for that which is the recommended way to do it in IIS, simply add a web.config with a rule like:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect to full domain" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^someserver$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://someserver.domain.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>

    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Would the above go in a redirect loop? since in my example both `someserver/` and `someserver.domain.com/` are on the same server

Comment: I think I found the question I should have been looking at - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18006963/iis-url-rewrite-for-redirect-to-fqdn
Thanks for pointing our the rewrite module is the way to do this